# How many bulbs are switched on?

Tags: mathematics

I remember this one from an interview:

> There is a room with 100 light bulbs (numbered from 1 to 100) lined up
>   in a row. All the bulbs are off. 100 people are lined up in front of
>   the room. The first person enters the room and switches on every bulb,
>   and exits. Then the second person enters and flips the switch on every
>   second bulb (bulbs 2, 4, 6, 8, ... are off). The third person enters and flips the switch on every third bulb (3,6,9,...) and so on until the 100th person exits the room. How many
>   of the light bulbs are on after the 100th person has exited the room?

Answer (score 3):

Let's choose a bulb, let's say $24$.

> Note that it's factors are $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24$ now is we give each of our people a number then note that people wearing these numbers are going to touch the switch of the bulb $24$. (It's pretty clear from question $b^{\text{th}}$ person will touch the bulbs from $b$'s multiple)
>
>  For $24$
>
>  `1: Switch on`
>  `2: off`
>  `3: on`
>  `4: off`
>  `6:on`
>  `8: off`
>  `12:on`
>  `24: off` 
>
>  So the numbers with total odd factors will be on at end. Only perfect square have odd factors.
>  Below and including $100$ there are total $\boxed{10}$ bulbs on.

Answer (score -1):

> the answer is 10.
>  the bulbs which will be on are 1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100.
>  because for this their are no persons to switch it off.
>  for example :34=2*17 i.e if 2 switches it on,it will be switched off by 17

Comment: Isn't 34 then switched back on by the 34th person?

Comment: 34 has 4 factors, that are 34-1,2,17,34.. so,basically 34 switches it off

Comment: Right, my mistake.

Comment: Your answer is confusing. First of all, 2 switches 34 off, not on. In general it is not true, that if n=a*b, (a<b), then one of a and b is switching it off, while the other one is switching it on. Also for all the numbers you list there is a person who does a temporary switch-off: for 4, it is person 2, for example, which contradicts your statement of not having a person to switch the bulb off.

Comment: @elias can u elaborate it properly.what you are trying to tell with example about n=a*b(a<b).

Comment: I'm just trying to emphasize that just because for 2*17=34, 2 switches off and 17 switches on, it is not necessary working in the same way for other numbers.

Comment: In fact for any perfect squares it is not true. 36=3*12, but both 3 and 12 are switching the bulb on.

Comment: 36 has 1*36,2*18,3*12,4*9,6*6 i.e odd number off factors.because in case of 6*6 only once 6 is getting chance to switch it on. so it will be in on state.

Comment: I hope you understood the answer @elias

Comment: I understand that 36 has odd factors, and that this is the reason why the corresponding lightbulb will be switched on in the end.
Still I think the answer you posted is confusing. It does not mention number of factors, just the final answer with some very vague handwaving, with the use of an example that is poorly chosen and unrealistic (again, for lightbulb 34, 2nd person switches it off, not on). Think about it: how does your example of 34 help someone understand what's happening with 81?